# 2 UIPageViewControllers gestures conflict

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I've got 2 UIPageViewControllers one inside other, both with horizontal scroll. One fullscreen, containing all the user info, another - photo gallery for this user. Behavior: when i swipe all the user photos, it swipes the fullscreen. But sometimes, i can't swipe photos, seems like this gesture is blocked, and it swipes only the first pager. But it unblocks when i make back swipe gesture. Here is a video, of what i'm talking about: https://youtu.be/Hr7tDKNv15A Help me find error causing it, at now I can't imagine how i need to debug that.

Overrided hitTest of container view, which stores inner pager:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if pointInside(point, withEvent: event) {
            print("Inside")
            print("Self view:\(self)")
            print("Self subviewsview:\(self.subviews)")
            print("Self subviewsview of subview:\(self.subviews[0].subviews)")

            return self.subviews[0].subviews[0]

        } else {
            print("Outside")
            return nil
        }

    }
```

That's my output, when i touch photos:

```
Inside
Self view:<armeniaApp.debugGesture: 0x7f7f8be46e60; frame = (0 0; 400 400); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f7f8be1e7c0>>
Self subviewsview:[<_UIPageViewControllerContentView: 0x7f7f8be920a0; frame = (0 0; 400 400); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f7f89ff1e00>>]
Self subviewsview of subview:[<_UIQueuingScrollView: 0x7f7f8a836e00; frame = (0 0; 400 400); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f7f8be81db0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f7f8be522b0>; contentOffset: {400, 0}; contentSize: {1200, 400}>]
```

So the gesture that i need stores in `UIQueuingScrollView` but what i need to do next? `return self.subviews[0].subviews[0]` doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail:

It seems like UIKit is getting confused as to which page controller to pass the gestures on to as they will both be listening for the same thing.

I'd imagine you want the outer page view controller's gesture recognisers (accessible as an array property: `self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers`) to require the gesture recognisers of the inner page view controller to fail. That way the swipe between photos will take precedence, but if there are no further photos to swipe to, you should be able to swipe between profiles.

Comment: Can't access that gestures, and so, delegate methods are not called :C In any places it says that gestureRecognizer array is empty( Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, just spotted this in the docs: "Only populated if transition style is `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`"

Comment: You could look at overriding `hitTest:` and making sure touches inside the inner page view controller get forwarded to it when it has further to scroll, but everything else gets forwarded to the outer page view controller?

Comment: stuck with that, there are so many layers, and they all are receiving my touches :\ Can you help which UIView i need to override? My structure is: Outer pager holds UserProfileVC(one from video), in which i got container view with embedded inner pager, which holds another photoVC(there is only uiimageview on it). At now, i'm just trying to find the view, which is responsible for photo swipes